# How to add a VTK widget on MFC window

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, vtk

I want to add some vtkSliderWidget or vtkCompassWidget on a MFC dialog program. But the example[Geovis/CompassWidget](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Geovis/CompassWidget) doesn't use MFC. And I tried to add these code in the OnInitDialog()

```
BOOL CvtkDLGDlg::OnInitDialog()
{

...

// Create the widget and its representation
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCompassRepresentation> compassRepresentation =     vtkSmartPointer<vtkCompassRepresentation>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCompassWidget> compassWidget =     vtkSmartPointer<vtkCompassWidget>::New();
compassWidget->SetInteractor(this->pvtkMFCWindow->GetInteractor());
compassWidget->SetRepresentation(compassRepresentation);
compassWidget->EnabledOn();

// execute object pipeline
ExecutePipeline();
return TRUE; 
}
```

There is no error during the building. However, when run the program no widget on the window. It makes me confused. I'd be very glad if someone could explain me what I'm doing wrong and point out a correct solution.

Thanks.

Comment: There is sample code that does use MFC. See [VTK/Examples/GUI/Win32/vtkMFC/](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/tree/master/Examples/GUI/Win32/vtkMFC). Preemptive warning: You will not be able to understand and use MFC, unless you are well versed in Windows API programming.

Comment: Thank you IInspectable. The sample code you mentioned is just the one I modified. But It didn't work.